# HOMEBREW - Installing Pygame on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: pygame, homebrew, osx-snow-leopard

So, I am trying to get pygame installed on my mac 10.6 via Homebrew. I am getting multiple errors
This is how I am installing Homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

That runs successfully in terminal. When I try and run the "brew" command to install mercurial
`brew install mercurial`and I get this error`-bash: brew: command not found`
I have tried to reinstall Homebrew multiple times, and it did not work. When I checked the /usr/local/bin/ directory, there was no file with "brew" in the name. I have also tried to run the command`pip3 install https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`, and I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Comment: I would double check that brew actually completed successfully. You are right - if it actually did succeed, that /usr/local/bin/brew would exist.

Comment: I have received no errors when I run the command, so I believe that would mean it installs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a full set of instructions here:
https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/82/homebrew-on-leopard-fails-to-install#comment-627494

```
brew install mercurial

brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf smpeg portmidi 
pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```